# Transformar células mescladas em nomes de colunas

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Caros,

tenho um arquivo excel que tem células mescladas no cabeçalho. Gostaria de importar e transformar esse arquivo num formato 'tidy'.

O arquivo está desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu importo e faço algumas limpezas (com o `slice()`, `janitor::row_to_names()` e `janitor::clean_names()`), termino com este data.frame:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei arrumar os nomes das colunas com esses códigos, mas não deu certo:

```
colunas <- names(df)
complemento <- as.character(df[1,])

new.name <- ifelse(is.na(colunas), complemento, colunas)

names(df) <- new.name
```

Gostaria de,   no final, como nomes das colunas algo como: partido, jan_dotacao, jan_distribuido, jan_gru, fev_dotacao, fev_distribuido e fev_gru. Desta forma, eu poderia transforma-lo em um tidy formato.

Alguém teria algumas dicas. Obrigado.

Segue a estrutura do df:

```
df <- structure(list(partido = c(NA, "AVANTE", "DEM", "MDB", "NOVO", 
"PATRI"), janeiro = c("Dotação", "1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", 
"4221437.7599999998", "2213062.5300000003", "1867686.28"), na = c("Distribuído", 
"1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998", 
"2213062.5300000003", "1867686.28"), na_2 = c("GRU (¹)", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), fevereiro = c("Dotação", "1545817.1800000002", 
"3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998", "2213062.5300000003", 
"1867686.28"), na_3 = c("Distribuído", "1545817.1800000002", 
"3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998", "2213062.5300000003", 
"1867686.28"), na_4 = c("GRU (¹)", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = 3:8, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `is.na` não funciona para os nomes porque são *strings* de texto. Pode usar `grepl`.

Comment: hum, verdade, obrigado por se atentar a isso e me informar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até existe um pacote para lidar com este tipo de situação, porém não me recordei aqui do nome. Segue uma solução mais "braçal":

```
library(tidyverse)

old_names <- df[1,] %>% unlist()

meses_aux <- names(df)

meses <- meses_aux[!str_detect(meses_aux,"na|partido")]

new_names <-
  c(
    "partido",
    paste0(rep(meses,each = 3),"_",old_names[-1]) %>%
      janitor::make_clean_names() %>% 
      str_remove("_1")
    
  )

df %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  set_names(new_names) %>% 
  glimpse()


Rows: 5
Columns: 7
$ partido               <chr> "AVANTE", "DEM", "MDB", "NOVO", "PATRI"
$ janeiro_dotacao       <chr> "1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998"~
$ janeiro_distribuido   <chr> "1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998"~
$ janeiro_gru           <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
$ fevereiro_dotacao     <chr> "1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998"~
$ fevereiro_distribuido <chr> "1545817.1800000002", "3581104.9399999999", "4221437.7599999998"~
$ fevereiro_gru         <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
```

Comment: muito obrigado, Vinícius, deu muito certo!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de ler o arquivo inteiro e fazer as limpezas, pode carregar apenas o cabeçalho, tratar os nomes e depois carregar o arquivo sem o cabeçalho e usar os nomes tratados.

Não sei qual pacote usa para ler arquivos Excel. Usei `readxl`, mas pode ser qualquer outro:

```
library(readxl)

cabecalho <- t(read_xlsx("planilha.xlsx", n_max = 2, col_names = FALSE))

cabecalho
#>      [,1]        [,2]
#> ...1 "partido"   NA
#> ...2 "janeiro"   "Dotação"
#> ...3 NA          "Distribuído"
#> ...4 NA          "GRU (¹)"
#> ...5 "fevereiro" "Dotação"
#> ...6 NA          "Distribuído"
#> ...7 NA          "GRU (¹)"
```

Agora preencher os NAs com o valor anterior e colar os nomes; usei a `zoo::na.locf` para isso. Ficará um "NA" no primeiro, usei `sub` para cortá-lo:

```
nomes <- sub(".NA", "", paste(zoo::na.locf(cabecalho[,1]), cabecalho[,2], sep = "_"))

nomes
#> [1] "partido"               "janeiro_Dotação"       "janeiro_Distribuído"   "janeiro_GRU (¹)"
#> [5] "fevereiro_Dotação"     "fevereiro_Distribuído" "fevereiro_GRU (¹)"
```

Por fim, ler o arquivo pulando o cabeçalho e usando os nomes tratados:

```
dados <- read_xlsx("planilha.xlsx", skip = 2, col_names = nomes)

dados
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   partido janeiro_Dotação janeiro_Distribuído `janeiro_GRU (¹)` fevereiro_Dotação fevereiro_Distribu… `fevereiro_GRU (¹…
#>   <chr>             <dbl>               <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>               <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 AVANTE         1545817.            1545817.                 0          1545817.            1545817.                  0
#> 2 DEM            3581105.            3581105.                 0          3581105.            3581105.                  0
#> 3 MDB            4221438.            4221438.                 0          4221438.            4221438.                  0
#> 4 NOVO           2213063.            2213063.                 0          2213063.            2213063.                  0
#> 5 PATRI          1867686.            1867686.                 0          1867686.            1867686.                  0
```

Note que ao não carregar linhas do cabeçalho como parte dos dados, as colunas são interpretadas no formato adequado, ao invés de todas como *character*.

Comment: obrigado, Carlos. Eu não havia pensado nesta lógica. É bastante válida, obrigado. Para carregar, como foi direto da internet, usei o pacote e função: 'rio::import(link)'. valeu!

Comment: O pacote é indiferente, desde que tenha a opção de ler/pular as linhas iniciais. Mas `rio::import` usa `readxl` par arquivos XLS, os argumentos são os mesmos.